# Непонятная конструкция switch

Tags: c#, switch

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В каких ситуациях используется такая конструкция switch?
В моем случае в зависимости от переданного в конструктор класса значения enum должно произойти определенное действие. Как мне может помочь такая конструкция?

Comment: Это [Pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching#compare-discrete-values) (сопоставление с образцом).

Comment: [switch expression - pattern matching expressions using the switch keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression)

Comment: Код здесь надо вставлять текстом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо `throw new NotImplementedException();`, реализуйте необходимые вам действия.

В данный момент, если поле `_dataEmployee`, является значениями `DataEmployee.FirstName`, `DataEmployee.LastName`,`DataEmployee.PhoneNumber` или`DataEmployee.Description` у вас срабатывают исключения. А если `_dataEmployee` не одно из этих значений, в `object value` возвратится `null`.

Т.е. если бы вы реализовали так:

```
object value = _dataEmployee switch
{
    DataEmployee.FirstName => 1,
    DataEmployee.LastName => 2,
    DataEmployee.PhoneNumber => 3,
    DataEmployee.Description => 4,
    _ => null
};
```

И в случае, если `_dataEmployee` равно значению `DataEmployee.FirstName`, то в `object value` возвратится `1`, а если `_dataEmployee` равно `DataEmployee.LastName`, то возвратится `2` и т.д.

Вместо этих значений `1`,`2`,`3`,`4` вам как раз нужно определить необходимые вам действия.

**PS**

В следующий раз, вставляйте код текстом, так как чтобы вам помочь, мне пришлось все значения прописывать ручками, вместо того, чтобы просто скопировать их.

Comment: Спасибо за совет в PS!